# Meta Tags appear two times

Tags: zend-framework2

Using this in my view:

```
<?= $this->headMeta()->appendName('keywords', 'my,keyword,etc,more'); ?>
<?= $this->headMeta()->appendName('description', $link->getMetaDesc()); ?>
<?= $this->headMeta()->appendName('title', $link->getMetaTitle()); ?>
```

But when i check the source code they appear two times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You echo the `headMeta()` ViewHelper multiple times...

```
<?php 
$this->headMeta()
     ->appendName('keywords', 'my,keyword,etc,more')
     ->appendName('description', $link->getMetaDesc())
     ->appendName('title', $link->getMetaTitle());

echo $this->headMeta();
?>
```

For clarification, you can use the `headMeta()` as often as you wish. However you should not echo it more than once ;)

```
$this->headMeta()->appendName(...);
$this->headMeta()->appendName(...);
$this->headMeta()->appendName(...);
$this->headMeta()->appendName(...);
$this->headMeta()->appendName(...);
$this->headMeta()->appendName(...);
$this->headMeta()->appendName(...);

echo $this->headMeta();
```

The above example is just as valid.

Answer (score 0):

Seems i should not use `$this->headMeta()` more than once.

This works:

```
<?= $this->headMeta()->appendName('keywords', $link->getMetaKeys())
                     ->appendName('description', $link->getMetaDesc()) 
                     ->appendName('title', $link->getMetaTitle()); ?>
```